# is ApiController capable of being added as a service reference?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0

Is an MVC4 ApiController capable of being added as a service reference?  I hope to avoid creating a redundant WCF service just so non-web applications can access my API.  I tried referencing one of my URL's as a service reference to a console app project and got an error:

> There was an error downloading

```
 'http://mypcname/WebServices.Data/api/Controllername/Get?epid=123&supressResults=false/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
```

> The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request. Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:

```
'http://mypcname/WebServices.Data/api/Conrollername/Get?epid=123&supressResults=false'.
```

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'. The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized. If the service is defined in the current solution, try
>   building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Comment: Have a look at this reference page, probably specifically the "Calling a Web API From a .NET Client" page: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients

Comment: I suggest looking at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

Comment: @Nate - That link is awesome, however it requires .NET 4.5.  We have some IIS6 machines in our environment which do not support 4.5.